# ESSL Separated Shader Objects : Output from vertex requires Input from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, opengl-es

Does anybody tried the separated shader objects on Android with ESSL 3.1 ? I want to create a shader without may output variables, but want to use a shader that ignore them.

Vertex Shader

```
#version 310 es
#extension GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks: enable
precision highp float;
out gl_PerVertex { vec4 gl_Position; float gl_PointSize; }; 
out vec2 texCoord0;
in vec4 attr_Vertex;
in vec2 attr_TexCoord;
void main()
{
   gl_Position = attr_Vertex;
   texCoord0 = attr_TexCoord;
}
```

Fragment Shader

Code :

```
#version 310 es
#extension GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks: enable
precision highp float;
void main() {} // Do nothing, (ie, for a depth only shader)
```

Go this error during pipeline validation

```
glValidateProgramPipeline(ppo);
glGetProgramPipelineiv(ppo, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, &status);
```

Output from glGetProgramPipelineInfoLog:

```
Error: output texCoord0 not declared in input from next stage.
```

On Android with ES 3.2, the message is

```
error: The fragment stage's input interface doesn't match preceding stage's output
```

However this is working on Desktop OpenGL and iOS with GL_EXT_shader_separated_objects

I have many vertex shaders and want to perform a depth pass or other only with a special fragment shader which don't need the input, or ignore them

Why output not declared in input from next stage is an error ? It should be at worst a warning, but not an error, and why it happens on ESSL 3.1 and not on Desktop (Also same shader on Desktop works - ie no error -)

According the documentation

> With separable program objects, interfaces between shader stages **may**
>   involve the outputs from one program object and the inputs from a
>   second program object

Apparently layout(location = xx) is required to not have the validation failed ?

Comment: "*this is working on Desktop OpenGL and iOS with GL_EXT_shader_separated_objects*" What *exactly* is "this" that is working? Show us your code that is producing this error. And not the GLSL code; the OpenGL code.

Comment: The code works on OpenGL 'Desktop' with GL_ARB_ES3_1_compatibility. It compiles and pipeline validate with glGetProgramPipelineiv, no error on (it is legit to not process the output varying from vertex in a fragment).